# Problem with iTunes Store and updating WhatsApp

Tags: itunes, iphone, itunes-store, whatsapp.app

So the problem is that I have an iPhone5 from my cousin, and yesterday I got a messages in WhatsApp from friends but I couldn't open WhatsApp. It said that I need to update WhatsApp. I went to the App Store and it required the password of iTunes Store but old email and password from my cousin, and I don't know the password.

Does someone have a solution for this? I also don't want to delete my WhatsApp because I cannot backup my chat history and also will not see the new messages that come in my WhatsApp.

Comment: Who bought WhatsApp from the store, you (with your own AppleID) or your cousin (with his)?

Comment: And if your cousin forgot his password -> https://iforgot.apple.com is the place to go.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds very much like the phone wasn't wiped & set up as your own new device.
This means that you will need the old login data for everything you need to do on the phone - this is not good.

You will need to get your cousin to make sure the phone is removed from his iCloud account, then you need to wipe it & start afresh.
You will lose all existing data, but currently, nothing on the phone belongs to you.

See [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/HT201351)

Answer (score -2):

Apple’s iOS 9.3.5 update creates issues with WhatsApp